# Eureka: Dynamic height of custom row

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I've made a custom cell, that should only has an `UIImageView`. The cell should change the height to fits the image, when the image is changed:

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

public class FirebaseImageCell: Cell<UIImage>, CellType{

    @IBOutlet weak var customImageView: UIImageView!

    public override func setup() {
        super.setup()
    }

    public override func update() {
        super.update()

        guard let image = row.value else { return }
        customImageView.image = image

        guard let cellWidth = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.frame.width else { return }
        height = { cellWidth * ( image.size.height / image.size.width ) }
    }

}

public final class FirebaseImageRow: Row<FirebaseImageCell>, RowType {
    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        cellProvider = CellProvider<FirebaseImageCell>(nibName: "FirebaseImageCell")
    }
}
```

I create the row like this:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "testImage")!

let testSection = Section("Test Section")
    <<< FirebaseImageRow("firebaseImageRow") { row in
            row.value = image
        }
form +++ testSection
```

At some point I want to change the image in the cell, and the cell should change it's height to fit the image. Here I change the image:

```
func imageChange() {

    guard let imageRow = form.rowBy(tag: "firebaseImageRow") as? FirebaseImageRow else { return }
    let image = UIImage(named: "testImage2")        
    imageRow.value = image
    imageRow.updateCell()

}
```

When the form is initialized the cell gets the right height, fittet to "testImage", but the height stay the same after the image is changed.

**How can I make the cell change it's height dynamically?**

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I answered you question, maybe you could try my function:

(1)You could create a NSMutableDictionary to remember the cell's height. When the height are changed then reload tableView or section or the indexPath.

(2) You also could user ReactiveCocoa to resolve that problem. And first of all,I suggest you to know about KVO, MVVM, Hook

(3) Our project set active image url like that: http://example.com/data/img.gif?width=271&height=360

so we can easy get the active imageView's size and update "heightForRowAtIndexPath:" function.

[image]
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

You might try it out that alternative:

```
<<< FormTextRow(tag: "phone", title: "Teléfono", isPhone: true).cellUpdate({ [weak self] cell, row in
         row.add(rule: RuleRequired(msg: "Debes indicar tu teléfono", id: "phone required"))
         row.add(rule: RuleMinLength(minLength: Locale.current.regionCode ?? "" == "CL" ? 6 : 10, msg: "Debes ingresar un número celular de 8 dígitos", id: "cell invalid"))
         if (self?.params["phone"] as? String ?? "") != row.value ?? "" {
             self?.params["phone"] = row.value ?? ""
             self?.updateParams?(self?.params ?? [:])
             cell.setupErrorMessage()
             self?.tableView.reloadData()
         }
     })
```

NOTE: `params` are the params to complete the form, `setupErrorMessage` is the rendering method and `reloadData` is for appears message purpose

Happy coding